# Java calling methods

Tags: java

I have two classes in separate files and I'm trying to import one class from the other. I was wondering how I could go about doing that? The the test class is supposed to take both methods from the first class and display them. I was wondering how I would go about doing that?

The first class:

```
public class StringUtils {
    public static String padLeft(String orig, int n) {
        orig = "testing for lab06";
        return String.format("%1$-" + n + "orig", orig);
    }

    public static String padLeft(String orig, int n, char c) {
        return String.format("%1$-" + n + c + "orig", orig);
    }
}
```

The second (or test) class

```
public class StringUtilsTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(padLeft);
        System.out.println(padLeft);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the classes in the same package?

Comment: If they're in the same package, you should be able to call them as `StringUtils.padLeft(orig,n)` and `StringUtils.padLeft(orig,n,c)` in StringUtilsTest

Comment: Well, assuming he has corresponding variables named `orig`, `n`, and `c` of the correct types in `main()`.

Comment: @DennisMeng Just put those as place holders since they are the parameter names

Comment: stringUtils.padLeft; only i think because it is static

Comment: What am I missing here? You *can't* print a method, only a variable!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both classes are in the same package (it looks like they're in the default package from the code in the question) you've got a couple of options.

The first option is to explicitly refer to the class containing the `padLeft` method like this:

```
public class StringUtilsTest
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    System.out.println(StringUtils.padLeft("test 1", 5));
    System.out.println(StringUtils.padLeft("test 2", 5));
  }
}
```

Had `StringUtils` and `StringUtilsTest` been in different packages (not that usual for a class and its test) you would have needed to import `StringUtils` into `StringUtilsTest` with a normal `import`.

The second option is to use a `import static` like this:

```
import static StringUtils.padLeft;

public class StringUtilsTest
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    System.out.println(padLeft("test 1", 5));
    System.out.println(padLeft("test 2", 5));
  }
}
```

Comment: This will probably work but is not a good way for a beginner to do it. At least until he understands how constructor in java works and the creation of objects of a certain type.

Comment: @JoaoFilipeClementeMartins the example looks as though it's using a *utils* class, which aren't commonly instantiated plus the methods on it are static make instantiation of a `StringUtils` pointless

Answer (score 0):

In java the main method is the one that is going to run the rest of the code. So what u need to do is inside the main create an object of type StringUtils:

```
public class StringUtilsTest{

public static void main(String[] args){
    StringUtils str = new StringUtils();
    System.out.println(str.padLeft("random string",5));
    System.out.println(str.padLeft("random string",5,"c"));
}
```

that str object now can hold the calls to the methods inside StringUtils class. 
For the methods to work properly you need to pass the arguments inside them like i did.

Note:
Like this you are using the default constructor for java classes if you want to define the constructor you have to do in the class StringUtils the following:

```
public class StringUtils{
    public StringUtils(){
        //and in here set the behavior you wish it to have.
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: the methods are static, declaring the object is not necessary

Comment: but provides a good understanding about how java is object oriented and it also works with non static methods

Comment: user3199687 did not say (s)he wanted to understand OOP. While your code is correct, it uses more memory to store `str`, uses more processing to create `str`, is slower to type, and is generally bad practice.